How can i write this code without goto statements
I have this psudeo code, it is just an idea for now. I am planning on writing it in c++, but i want to write it such that it doesn't use goto statements, i know i should use functions and all but how can i backtrack and jump to different states without goto statements? like maybe i want to go from idle straight to landed or from landed back to idle, how can this be done?
Commands are sent to serial port, whenever i need to send them
Turn on
Initialize sensors
Idle mode:
    if eeprom flag is true 
        go to recovered state
    while on command not receieved
        wait for on command
    
launch_wait:
    while altitude is constant
        if reset command set eeprom to false  goto idle
        if calibration command received
            calibrate sensors
        send telemetry
Launch:
    while altitude is increasing
        if reset command received
            set eeprom to false  
            goto idle
        send telemetry
Descend:
    while altitude is decreasing
        if reset command received
            set eeprom to false  
            goto idle
        release heat shield
        release parachute
        send telemetry
Landed:
    while altitude is constant
        if reset command received
            set eeprom to false 
            goto idle
        make buzzer beep
Simulation:
    do simulation stuff
    go to idle



The pseudocode is immediately broken, as I don't see a recovered state?

Look at implementing State Machine Logic

To go from one of those labels to any of the others? Just use goto. To go from any one to idle? Use a while or do/while and use continue.

@sweenish the recovered state is a general term for any of the states whichever one is recovered is the one it goes to

I'm not sure this is answerable as of now. If you were to read your pseudo code line by line it would not be possible to logically reach the end of your pseudo code. For example, one line says to wait for on command and nothing actually sends an on command.

@ApplePie my bad let me rewrite it to be clear

I'd suggest you to at least post C++ code with goto. It'll be easy for us to reason about it.

@itprorh66 https://github.com/jrullan/StateMachine like this one?

I find functions with smartly-placed returns, loops, and conditionals like if and switch eliminate the need for most gotos.

If you use an enum to name the states and a while loop with a switch inside you could do this: https://onlinegdb.com/ogZxta4sp

@JerryJeremiah thank you so much you the goat fr, i will either do like what you did or use a FSM thank you

I love writing FSMs, my favorite tool for that is coroutings.

And the Flying Spaghetti Monster loves you.

Yes, you referenced library is the basic idea, of course you will have to implement with your states and transition conditions.

If the algorithm is correctly composed, simplest implementation is a switch statement inside an infinite loop with fall through cases and some continues. But theer can be other implementations too.for(;;) switch (state){default: update(state); continue; case all_states::state_1: handle_state1; continue;};. States can be defined in an enum for clarity
